# Importing DBF files to MS Excel 2007

Tags: import, excel-2007, dbf

I am trying to import DBF file to Excel.
But after I am importing it, it doesnt show data in proper format. I guess there is some problem with encoding. I tried using different encodings in "File Origin" option. 
Could anybody guide me in this matter.?

Thanks

Comment: What does "it doesnt show data in proper format" mean? Give examples of both actual and expected results. Can you publish an example file somewhere?

Comment: @JohnMachin : by not in proper format I mean to say it is showing garbage characters which are not their in database. May be there is some problem in encoding

Comment: Maybe somebody has a crystal ball. Otherwise show examples of what's in the database and what you are getting in Excel.

Comment: I can show actual and expected results as I am not suppose to give any details about this database online. sorry. Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is an encoding issue indeed. Windows "translates" your DBF characters to the default system code page when opening the file. There are ways around if you know your original code page but it is not for the faint hearted.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Excel DbfMate Add-In](http://www.news2news.com/vfp/?solution=14). It allows importing data from DBF files directly to worksheet, and exporting data from worksheets to DBF files using either GUI or VBA. Handles character encoding. Supported Excel versions: 2007 to 2013. Supported DBF formats: dBase III, VFP, dBase IV (import only). A demo is also available on [Softpedia](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Internet/Servers/Database-Utils/Excel-DbfMate.shtml).